# If $f$ is a convex function in $(a,b)$ then $|f|$ is convex function in $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **TRUE or FALSE:**
>
> If $f$ is a convex function in $(a,b)$ then $|f|$ is convex function in $(a,b)$.

**My Proof:**

Since $f$ is convex function so, $f(tx+(1-t)y)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ , for all $x,y\in (a,b)$ and for $0<t<1.$

Let, $g=|f|$.

Now $g(tx+(1-t)y)=|f|(tx+(1-t)y)=|f(tx+(1-t)y)|\le |tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)|\le t|f(x)|+(1-t)|f(y)|=t|f|(x)+(1-t)|f|(y)=tg(x)+(1-t)g(y).$

So, $|f|$ is also convex function in $(a,b)$.

Is my proof correct ? If wrong then please give an example of such a function $f$ such that $|f|$ is NOT convex...

**Update: 25th May 2015**

According to the answer of '   Przemysław Scherwentke  ' I understand that if $f$ is convex then $|f|$ may not be convex..His example is $f(x)=x^2-1$.

Since , $f''(x)=2>0$ , so $f$ is convex.. **But I am unable to understand how $|f|$ is NOT convex**. I tried through the definition of convex function but I can not do it..

Comment: Try to draw some picture (e.g $f(x) = x^2 - 1)$)

Comment: What's more, if $f$ is a negative convex function on $(a, b)$, then $|f|$ is concave on $(a, b)$.

Comment: That means if $f$ is concave in $(a,b)$ then $|f|$ is also concave ?

Comment: So, where my defect in my proof ?? That means I want to know that after which step I can not proceed ?

Comment: $|f(tx+(1-t)y)|\le |tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)|$ is incorrect (e.g. $-2<-1$ does not imply $|-2| <|-1|$)

Comment: Ohhh!!! Yes.....Thanks..

Comment: @John):Can you give me proof that , if $f$ is concave then $|f|$ is also concave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one definition of convexity is that the tangent is below the graph at least locally. now take a convex function that takes both positive and negative values, for example, $f(x) = x^2 - 1.$ now the graph of $y = |x^2 - 1|$ is old graph in the region $|x| \ge 1$ but for $-1 \le x \le 1$ it get reflected on the $x$-axis. the tangent that were below the graph now is above the graph. so the graph of $y = |x^2 - 1|$ is convex(concave up) in $|x| \ge 1$ and concave down on $-1 \le x \le 1.$

Comment: ' Tangent is below the graph ' means ??

Comment: let $c \in (a, b).$ then  $f(c) + (x-c)f'(c) < f(x) \text{ for } a < x < b$ is the algebraic equivalent of saying that the tangent at $(c, f(c)$ is below the graph of $y = f(x)$ locally around $x = c.$ in fact it may be easier to characterize convexity in terms of the secant line instead of the tangent. any way geometric intuition is much more important than a string of equalities.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider, e.g., $f(x)=x^2-1$.

Comment: Since , $f''(x)=2>0$ so $f$ is convex..But how $|f|$ is NOT ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 $|f|$ is not differentiable in $\pm1$. Please draw its graph.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 No, it  means it is not dierentiable in $+1$ and it is not dierentiable in $-1$. Hence for example this $f$ on $(-2,2)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 OK. Thanks,

Comment: Actually $|f|$ is not convex, not because it is not differentiable (A convex function does not have to be differentiable).

Comment: @John Certainly. S.Panja-1729 suggested, that $|f|''=2$ everywhere.

Comment: @ Przemysław Scherwentke): Please give details how $|f|$ is NOT convex ?

Comment: ^Since $|f(0)| = 1 > 0 = \tfrac{1}{2}|f(-1)|+\tfrac{1}{2}|f(1)|$, we have that $|f|$ is not convex.